# How to iterate & perform operation over columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Below is the snapshot of data-set. Now i want to write function to compute column wise maxima, minima,mean etc for each parameter 1,2,3.... wrt to each category.]

Can someone pls suggest the approach/code to work on this data-set. Need to write a user defined function for each category to compute maxima, minima etc for each parameter column.

Here is code snipped which i tried-

```
def stats(parameter):
    print("######################")
    print(parameter)
    max = parameter.max()
    mean = parameter.mean()
    min = parameter.min()
    print("stats function executed")
for column in df1.ix[:,2:]:
    print(column)
    stats(column)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `df1[]` for select column:

```
for column in df1.ix[:,2:]:
    print(column)
    stats(df1[column])
```

But better is use [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with [`describe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['10-01-2017','10-01-2017','11-01-2017'],
                   'Categories':['Ca1','Cat1','Cat2'],
                   'Parameter1':[7,8,9],
                   'Parameter2':[1,3,5],
                   'Parameter3':[5,3,6],
                   'Parameter3':[7,4,3]})

print (df1)
  Categories        Date  Parameter1  Parameter2  Parameter3
0        Ca1  10-01-2017           7           1           7
1       Cat1  10-01-2017           8           3           4
2       Cat2  11-01-2017           9           5           3

df = df1.filter(like='Parameter').describe()
print (df)
       Parameter1  Parameter2  Parameter3
count         3.0         3.0    3.000000
mean          8.0         3.0    4.666667
std           1.0         2.0    2.081666
min           7.0         1.0    3.000000
25%           7.5         2.0    3.500000
50%           8.0         3.0    4.000000
75%           8.5         4.0    5.500000
max           9.0         5.0    7.000000
```

Last is possible filter output:

```
L = ['mean','max','min']
print (df.loc[L])
      Parameter1  Parameter2  Parameter3
mean         8.0         3.0    4.666667
max          9.0         5.0    7.000000
min          7.0         1.0    3.000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `groupby` and the built-in `describe` function you can get:

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Categories': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'Param1': [42, 10, 123.23, 0.1], 'Param2': 
   ...: [13, 16, 12.23, -2]})

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
  Categories  Param1  Param2
0          a   42.00   13.00
1          a   10.00   16.00
2          b  123.23   12.23
3          b    0.10   -2.00

In [9]: df.groupby('Categories').describe()
Out[9]: 
                      Param1     Param2
Categories                             
a          count    2.000000   2.000000
           mean    26.000000  14.500000
           std     22.627417   2.121320
           min     10.000000  13.000000
           25%     18.000000  13.750000
           50%     26.000000  14.500000
           75%     34.000000  15.250000
           max     42.000000  16.000000
b          count    2.000000   2.000000
           mean    61.665000   5.115000
           std     87.066058  10.062129
           min      0.100000  -2.000000
           25%     30.882500   1.557500
           50%     61.665000   5.115000
           75%     92.447500   8.672500
           max    123.230000  12.230000
```

And if you unstack this you get:

```
In [10]: df.groupby('Categories').describe().unstack()
Out[10]: 
           Param1                                                             \
            count    mean        std   min      25%     50%      75%     max   
Categories                                                                     
a             2.0  26.000  22.627417  10.0  18.0000  26.000  34.0000   42.00   
b             2.0  61.665  87.066058   0.1  30.8825  61.665  92.4475  123.23   

           Param2                                                            
            count    mean        std   min      25%     50%      75%    max  
Categories                                                                   
a             2.0  14.500   2.121320  13.0  13.7500  14.500  15.2500  16.00  
b             2.0   5.115  10.062129  -2.0   1.5575   5.115   8.6725  12.23
```

Comment: Thanks @languitar for the descriptive answer & enhancing the knowledge in pandas functions.